# How can several input lines be combined in a single string?

Tags: python, string

I'm in Python 3 trying to create a program that analyzes a text.
The program asks for an input (should be always a string) like this

```
text=input('Inster a text: ')
```

In principle, if I input something like

```
> Today was my best day at the restaurant
```

my program performs his calculations right (i.e. understands the whole input as a single string).

The problem comes when I try to insert a complex text like the first 9 verses of the Divine Comedy (when asked for that input).

```
> Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita
mi ritrovai per una selva oscura,
ché la diritta via era smarrita.

Ahi quanto a dir qual era è cosa dura
esta selva selvaggia e aspra e forte
che nel pensier rinova la paura!

Tant' è amara che poco è più morte;
ma per trattar del ben ch'i' vi trovai,
dirò de l'altre cose ch'i' v'ho scorte.
```

In this case:

1. It interprets the apostrophes marks (') as enclosing a text. Making the rest of the text looks like a series of commands (for example the **altre cose ch** part in the last verse becomes a string and the text written out of that becomes a series of commands)
2. It interprets the "del" word (that appears in the first and eigth lines) as the command *delete*
3. It interprets the "dir" word (that appears in the fourth line) as the command *direction*

I discovered that if I add a double apostrophe (") at the beggining and the end of the text and if the text apeared in 1 single line then it interprets the input right (as an entire string). To include the (") at the beginning and end of my input text is not a great deal, but the part when I make the text appear in a single line (combining the verses in a single sequence by adding `\` at the end of each verse for example) is extremely tedious when introducing large texts.

How can my program interpret some input like that as an entire string and avoid all of this problems? (one way of solving is answering the question: how can I combine several code lines in a single string sequence without spending hours?)

Comment: read text from file - it simpler. Or create GUI.

Comment: Note: If `input` interprets stuff, then you are _not_ using Python 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the multiple-lines-of-input thing: One way to solve this would be to require the user to enter some sort of stop-word when the input is finished:

```
def multiline_input(prompt, end="END"):
    lines = []
    line = input("{} (enter {} to end input): ".format(prompt, end))
    while line != end:
        lines.append(line)
        line = input()
    return "\n".join(lines)

s = multiline_input("enter stuff")
```

Another common practice is to accept input until the user enters a blank line, but for your example, this would not work. You could wait for two consecutive blank lines, though.

But note: if your `input` function is interpreting stuff, like quotation marks or Python keywords, then you are not using Python 3.x but Python 2. Either make sure to *really* use Python 3, or use `raw_input` instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is using Python 2.x as well, upvoted for the solution which will be useful for other problems.

Answer (score 3):

`input()` reads from keyboard till you press `Enter`.

But you can use `sys.stdin.read()` to read till you press Ctrl+D (tested on Linux) which sends `EOF` (end of file) inforamtion. (on Windows it may be Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Z).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

a = sys.stdin.read()

print('result:', a)
```

---

**BTW:** to display different prompt for different platform:

```
import sys

if sys.platform.startswith('win32'): 
     # Ctrl+Z is used by cmd.exe on Windows
     print('Input multiline text and press "Ctrl+Z"')
else: 
     # Ctrl+D is used by linux, freebsd, probably mac
     print('Input multiline text and press "Ctrl+D"')
```

see: [sys.platform](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.platform)

Comment: Nice, but you should tell the user how to end the input, and _if_ that's different on different systems (running Linux myself, so can't try) this might be a problem.

Comment: @tobias_k but I said `Ctrl+D` on Linux or probably Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Z on Windows (not tested - I don't use Windows any more) :)

Comment: Sure, I did not mean that you should tell OP, but that OP has to be able to tell the user, e.g. in the input prompt. _If_ that's different on different systems, you have to determine it at runtime, which might be tricky.

Comment: @tobias_k now I get it.